# mysql login attempts log

Tags: mysql, sql, logging

I created a MySQL database on my server.
As a part of that i open a port to coming connection,
Now i want to log all the login attempts to the server.
I succeeded to log only the unames of them by reading the packets but it's seems that i cant recover the passwords.

Comment: It is not possible for the server to log plain passwords used in login attempts, as the client only sends hashed tokens (not only, but also, to prevent things like getting passwords by just reading network packets).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this procedure

```
#grep "A temporary password" /var/log/mysqld.log
```

You will see your default password. then again reset your password:

```
#systemctl start mysqld.service 
#mysql_secure_installation
Your root password default get from 1st command then used it for recover password
```